# How do I get current week's count data from table in Laravel

Tags: mysql, arrays, database, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get this current week's data from my table

I have the following code which gives me 31 days of data (A month but it's separated which is what I need)

```
$stats["tmv"] = "";
$stats["tmd"] = "";
$stats["tru"] =  array();

        for ($i=1; $i <= 31; $i++) {
            $stats["tmv"] .= DB::table('stats')->select(DB::raw('*'))->where(DB::raw('DAY(created_at)'), '=', $i)->where('stats_type', "mv")->count();
            $stats["tmd"] .= DB::table('stats')->select(DB::raw('*'))->where(DB::raw('DAY(created_at)'), '=', $i)->where('stats_type', "md")->count();
            $stats["tru"][$i] = DB::table('users')->select(DB::raw('*'))->where(DB::raw('DAY(created_at)'), '=', $i)->count();

            if ($i != 31) {
                $stats["tmv"] .= ",";
                $stats["tmd"] .= ",";
            }
        }
```

Output:

```
"tmv" => "11,4,1,13,0,5,15,2,0,24,1,7,17,18,45,14,31,61,3,1,4,1,1,27,30,47,18,60,10,0,156"
```

How do I edit my query to select this current week's data but still output the count like:

```
"11,4,1,13,0,5,15"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code generates a lot of queries which is really bad. There are many ways to get data you want with one query. For example, using Eloquent:

```
Stats::where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->startOfWeek())
     ->where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->endOfWeek())
     ->get();
```

If you want to get data for another week and not the current one, use another Carbon object like `Carbon::parse('2017-05-01')` instead of `Carbon::now()`

Comment: I tried that and I get 
"tmv" => "48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48"

I'm trying to count the days data in the week and not the entire week itself.

Comment: @rebirth1078 I can't see your DB data, how exactly you're get the data and what exactly result you're expecting, so I can't help here, but I'm pretty sure my code works perfectly if you want to get data for the current week only.

Comment: yeah it works perfectly fine for getting this week's data, I'm going to try to make it work with another foreach